# Generics from interface method are stripped

Tags: java, generics

I have this interface:

```
public interface Persistant<T extends BaseDaoEnabled<T, UUID>> extends Identifiable {

T getSelf();

default <P> P getInstance(DataKey<P> key) {
    return key.getDefaultInstance();
}
```

and a class that implements it. My problem is that when I call `obj.getInstance(DataKeys.X)`, X being a `DataKey<X>` object, the return type of this method is `Object` and not `X`, the generic type is stripped. When I put the method inside my object class (not interface), it works just fine. **See the screenshot below**:

First method is from the interface, 2nd method is from the class. They both have the SAME signature

[image]

Comment: What's your Java version and which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, Java 1.8-151

Comment: Do you mind giving a **real** [mcve] - minimal code to repro the error?

Comment: I think that IDEA's code completion and Java compiler may give different results - try to compile the code regardless of IDEA and see if you get a compilation error. And an unrelated question: How is `getInstance` related to the interface? It seems to me it's a completely separated piece of code.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `target`, as text, in the question. And the declaration of `BaseDaoEnabled`, and show where `UUID` is declared. In short: please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I tried compiling manually and it gave me the same error: inconvertible types. The getInstance method is just an example that returns an R type object, it could be replaced by foo for example. target is the `obj` that I used on my text.

Comment: (but in any case, the answer is going to be that you have a raw type somewhere).

Comment: What is the signature for `Identifiable` - is it perhaps generic?

Comment: How do you define `target`?

Comment: `Resident target = ...`. Identifiable is not generic.

Comment: That appears to be the problem then. It takes a generic argument. eg. Resident<X>.

Answer (score 1):

The interface has a type parameter (`Persistant<T...>`) that I forgot to include on my `Resident/obj` class. I was implementing it by just using `implements Persistant`, implementing it using `implements Persistant<Resident>` fixed my issue!